# ¿Por qué plotly no muestra la gráfica, cuando ejecutos las mismas sentencias dentro de una clase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, plotly

Estoy aprendiendo clases. El siguiente script, muestra la gráfica correctamente utilizando plotly express, pero si lo integro como método en una clase, no lo hace.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr 
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
from plotly.offline import iplot
import plotly.express as px 

class ImportadorCotizaciones:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cotizaciones = None
        self.start = "2000-1-4"
        self.end = date.today()
        self.cotizaciones = None

    def Importar_cotizaciones(self):

        dicc_tickers = {"IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "TEF.MC":"Telefonica", "^IBEX":"Ibex35" }
        dfs = []
        nombres = []

        for (k,v) in dicc_tickers.items():
            self.cotizaciones_de_ticker = pdr.DataReader(k, 'yahoo', self.start, self.end)
            self.cotizaciones_de_ticker = self.cotizaciones_de_ticker[["Close"]]
            self.cotizaciones_de_ticker = self.cotizaciones_de_ticker.rename(columns={"Close": v})

            dfs.append(self.cotizaciones_de_ticker)

        dfs = iter(dfs)
        self.cotizaciones = next(dfs)
        for df_ in dfs:
            self.cotizaciones = self.cotizaciones.merge(df_, on='Date')

class Indicadores:
    def __init__(self, importador):
        self.importador = importador 
    
    def dibujar_grafico(self):
        self.aux_val_ind = importador.cotizaciones[["Iberdrola", "Ibex35"]].pct_change().dropna() 
        df = self.aux_val_ind.copy(deep=True)
        df['Media'] = df.mean(axis = 1) 
        # Usando plotly.express       
        px.line((df + 1).cumprod() ,y=df.columns ,title=f"\nValor de 1€ invertido desde el { importador.start}  hasta el {importador.end} ")

importador = ImportadorCotizaciones()
importador.Importar_cotizaciones()
importador.cotizaciones[:3] 

indicadores = Indicadores(importador)
indicadores.dibujar_grafico()
```

El script que funciona fuera de la clase es:

```
# Usando plotly.express
from plotly.offline import iplot
import plotly.express as px

start = "2000-1-4"
end = date.today()
aux_val_ind = importador.cotizaciones[["Iberdrola", "Ibex35"]].pct_change().dropna() 
df = aux_val_ind.copy(deep=True)
df['Media'] = df.mean(axis = 1) 

px.line((df + 1).cumprod() ,y=df.columns ,title=f"\nValor actual de 1€ invertido el {start} ")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Dónde está mi fallo?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un fallo difícil de encontrar por su sencillez.

Lo que te ocurre es que tu método `.dibujar_grafico()` no retorna nada. Por tanto el gráfico no se imprime por pantalla. Para resolverlo solo hay que añadir el `return` al final de la función. Tu método `.dibujar_gráfico()` quedaría así:

```
 def dibujar_grafico(self):
    self.aux_val_ind = importador.cotizaciones[["Iberdrola", "Ibex35"]].pct_change().dropna() 
    df = self.aux_val_ind.copy(deep=True)
    df['Media'] = df.mean(axis = 1)        
    return px.line((df + 1).cumprod() ,y=df.columns ,title=f"\nValor de 1€ invertido desde el { importador.start}  hasta el {importador.end} ")
```